# Setting up Apache2 ubuntu non-ssl Server to handle incoming wss://

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl, websocket, proxypass

I am running a video chat program on my SSL site, but need to use a non-SSL server for the chat media server. Here is my setup:

- Chat server is running on non-SSL Apache2 ubuntu Amazon instance on port 8080 (checked port is open and running)
- Chat is sitting on ssl server using wss://[myserver]/wss/
- I've enabled proxy_wstunnel on the server
- I’ve added the ProxyPass to the apache2 virtual host

> SSLProxyEngine On
>
> ProxyPass /wss/ ws://[myserver]:8080

The chat is running on the server end just fine (aside from video and audio because it’s non-ssl)

It’s not working properly while sitting on the SSL server. I’m getting this error on the screen: “Websocket closed, please try reloading page later.” and this is the error in the console: “WebSocket connection to ‘wss://[myserver]/wss/?room=3’ failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR”

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Update: After enabling ALL proxy modules, I was able to get this to work. This was the reference that saved me days of headache: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension